# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat

**Hello**
this is my first experience with android studio andI have this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhTaw.png)

I'm using android studio 2.3.2

I tried so many solutions but still not work

**Build.gradle(project:justjava3)**

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Build.gradle(module:app) :**

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.majed.justjava"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Please Help Me**

Comment: try to update you build gradle to 3.4.0

Comment: There is no version 29 (or above) of appcompat. The old support libraries stopped at 28. If you want to upgrade beyond that, you'll need to migrate to androidx.

Comment: As said, there is no AppCompat 29. Where did you get this example? Can you let the author know they have an error in their code? Was this a default in Android Studio? Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As in the attached image the error log is showing to install repository and sync project. So click on the option and install the repository and after syncing successfully , clean and rebuild the project.

One more thing, the build gradle version you are using is '2.3.2' which is outdated.

See the latest version for more info-

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: I try to upgrade gradle to 5.4.1 but another error faced me : Error:Cause: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.ModuleComponentIdentifierImpl.getModuleIdentifier()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleIdentifier;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **there is no 29.x version of support library**.

The last version of `support-library` is 28.0.0 and further development is moved to `androidx` package.

[Official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library)

> Note: With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called **AndroidX** which is part of Jetpack. The AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also includes the latest Jetpack components.
>
> You can continue to use the support library. Historical artifacts (those versioned 27 and earlier, and packaged as android.support.*) will remain available on Google Maven. **However, all new library development will occur in the AndroidX library.**
>
> We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX as well.